# Consolidation of two Worksheets Execution Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to consolidate two Worksheets (`Sheet 5` and `Sheet 3`). More precisely, I am adding the data from `Sheet 5` to `Sheet 3` what is working smooth as long as have opened `Sheet 3` when processing the code. However, when I switch to another sheet and run the code, the code doesn't work properly anymore.

1. When I run the code for the first time it works smooth
2. When I run the code repeatedly nothing should happen, because my macro just inserts data from `Sheet 5` in `Sheet 3`that isn't already in `Sheet 3` and since this data has already been inserted in the first run nothing should happen. This is the case, when I stay on `Sheet 3`. However, if I switch to another sheet and run the code a second, third, fourth time, then the macro is partly executed everytime.

Let me explain this a lil bit further:

For my tests I am using three rows with data. When I execute the button a first time, all three rows in `Sheet 5` are added to `Sheet 3`. When I press the button a second, third, fourth time three rows are added to `Sheet 3`

- First added row: Is empty
- Second & Third added row: contain the data of the second and third row in `Sheet 3`

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here?

```
    Sub Consolidation()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim NFR As Long


    lastrow = Tabelle5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NFR = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-3).Row
    Set myrange = Tabelle5.UsedRange


    For i = 4 To lastrow

    On Error Resume Next

    If Tabelle3.Cells(5 + i, 1) <> "" And Not IsError(Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(5 + i, 1), Tabelle5.Range("A:A"), False)) Then


        Tabelle3.Cells(5 + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(5 + i, 1), myrange, 2, False)

    End If


    If IsError(Application.Match(Tabelle5.Cells(i, 1), Tabelle3.Range("A9:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row), False)) Then


        Tabelle3.Cells(NFR + i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle5.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 1, False)


        Tabelle3.Cells(NFR + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle5.Cells(i, 1), myrange, 2, False)


      End If

    Next i

    Set Rng = Tabelle3.Range("A9:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row)
    On Error Resume Next
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete



    End Sub
```

Comment: Removing the `On Error Resume Next` would be a good start: instead use the non-Worksheetfunction version of VLookup and test the return values for errors.  That way you won't get runtime errors if vlookup fails.

Comment: Also, this has no sheet reference which may be screwing things up `Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row`.

Comment: @SJR: You were right, that solved the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @TimWilliams : Can you be so kind and explain your idea a lil bit further? :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
Sub Consolidation()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim NFR As Long, r, v

    lastrow = Tabelle5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NFR = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-3).Row
    Set myrange = Tabelle5.UsedRange


    For i = 4 To lastrow

        v = Tabelle3.Cells(5 + i, 1)
        If v <> "" And Not IsError(Application.Match(v, Tabelle5.Range("A:A"), False)) Then

            r = Application.VLookup(v, myrange, 2, False)
            Tabelle3.Cells(5 + i, 2) = IIf(IsError(r), "No match", r)

        End If

        v = Tabelle5.Cells(i, 1)
        If IsError(Application.Match(v, Tabelle3.Range("A9:A" & _
               Tabelle3.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row), False)) Then

            r = Application.VLookup(v, myrange, 1, False)
            Tabelle3.Cells(NFR + i, 1) = IIf(IsError(r), "No match", r)

            r = Application.VLookup(v, myrange, 2, False)
            Tabelle3.Cells(NFR + i, 2) = IIf(IsError(r), "No match", r)
        End If

    Next i

    Set Rng = Tabelle3.Range("A9:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row)

    On Error Resume Next
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, I see your point :) But what is better about this method? When I fixed the `range` definition as described by SJR my code is working smooth with the `On Errror Resume Next` line.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` ignores all errors (even unexpected ones) so it's best to avoid it unless necessary.  That way you're not missing potential issues which could affect  the reliability of your code.